# Best Development Framework for a Google-Maps-ish Web Application?

Tags: jquery, silverlight, flash, html, gwt

I am starting a project in which I hope to create a web application with similar elements to Google Maps, such as zooming, panning, displaying tiles, etc.  The idea would be for it to have a very fluid and dynamic feel.

Some possibilities that I have encountered are:

-Flash

-Silverlight

-HTML5

-Google Web Toolkit

-Javascript/jQuery

Being proficient in C# and .net, I feel that Silverlight may be the easiest for me to work with.  I am worried however with regards to the penetration of Silverlight (this is a consumer-facing application).

Please note that I am not asking to implement Google Maps into my web application.  Rather I am attempting to create a new similar website (not mapping, but similar concepts).

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing how Google Maps itself is an HTML/JavaScript/CSS application I'd suggest going the HTML5 route. The main advantage is penetration into the mobile market, especially on Android/iPhone/iDevices which support HTML5 out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

There's a virtually ready-to-go solution as OpenLayers Mobile:

http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/mobile.html

Another example here, with jQuery mobile for added mobile goodness:

http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/mobile-jq.html#mappage

Displays tiles, vectors, map layers (if you need them) and so on. The tiles don't even need to be geographic, you can use it to display large images.

Its the mobile branch of OpenLayers. Oh, and it's open source. Whatever you do, don't go for Flash or Silverlight. Massive deadends.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Silverlight and C#, then you should have a look at the [bing maps silverlight control](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/isdk/silverlight/). I know you said that you were not making a maps application, but depending how similar the application is, you could still use the same control. You can specify your own tile source with the map control, which means the tiles don't have to be map tiles at all.